# I got stuck in switching tabs with animations as there are limitations in CSS properties

Tags: css, reactjs

```
   <div className="product-information-tabs">
        <nav>
           <div className="nav nav-tabs">
               <a href="#" className={`nav-link ${activeTab === "Description" ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={(e) => {
                 e.preventDefault()
                 setActiveTab("Description")
               }}>
                   Description
               </a>
               <a href="#" className={`nav-link ${activeTab === "Additional Information" ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault()
                  setActiveTab("Additional Information")
               }}>
                   Additional Information
               </a>
            </div>
          </nav>
           <div className="tab-content">
               <div className={`tab-pane fade ${activeTab === "Description" ? "active show" : ""}`}> 
                         Some Content  
               </div>
               <div className={`tab-pane fade ${activeTab === "Additional Information" ? "active show" : ""}`}>
                        Some Content  
               </div>
               <div className={`tab-pane fade ${activeTab === "Specification" ? "active show" : ""}`}>
                        Some Content  
               </div>
               <div className={`tab-pane fade ${activeTab === "Review" ? "active show" : ""}`}>
                        Some Content  
                </div>
           </div>
  </div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.fade{
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear; 
}
.fade:not(.show){
  opacity: 0; 
  visibility: hidden;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane{ 
  display: none; 
}
.tab-content > .active.show{
  display: block;
  opacity: 1; 
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I have an issue that when trying to switch tabs with animations got various limitations if I want to have the content only be displayed when the classname has `active` but without animations since display properties could not be applied to transition properties. However, I had also tried to use `opacity` and `visibility` properties but without display properties will make the content have too much redundant spaces so are there any best ways to have the content only be displayed when active with transitions but without any redundant spaces?

I tried and tried again and could not find a solution that satisfies the conditions so would like to seek help for solutions as there are much limitations to have properties satisfied. Also I took some references from other websites and tried to apply but it still could not take in effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should set a class name for the current tab to fade it out and then apply a class name to change its display to `none`(these two process shouldn't happen at the same time) and then you should show the new tab by setting its `display` to `block`. Here there's an issue that setting `display` and `opacity` at the same time doesn't trigger the animation. You can use css `keyframes` to have the appearing animation.

Here's a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eskkgt?file=src%2FApp.js

`App.js`

```
const TRANSITION_DURATION = 150;

export default function App() {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState('Description');
  const [showTab, setShowTab] = React.useState('Description');

  const changeTab = (tabName) => {
    setShowTab(tabName);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setActiveTab(tabName);
    }, TRANSITION_DURATION);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ '--TRANSITION_DURATION': TRANSITION_DURATION + 'ms' }} className="product-information-tabs">
        <nav>
          <div className="nav nav-tabs">
            <a
              href="#"
              className={`nav-link ${
                activeTab === 'Description' ? 'active' : ''
              }`}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                changeTab('Description');
              }}
            >
              Description
            </a>
            <a
              href="#"
              className={`nav-link ${
                activeTab === 'Additional Information' ? 'active' : ''
              }`}
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                changeTab('Additional Information');
              }}
            >
              Additional Information
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className="tab-content">
          <div
            className={`tab-pane fade ${
              activeTab === 'Description' ? 'active' : ''
            } ${showTab === 'Description' ? 'show' : ''}`}
          >
            Some Content 1
          </div>
          <div
            className={`tab-pane fade ${
              activeTab === 'Additional Information' ? 'active' : ''
            } ${showTab === 'Additional Information' ? 'show' : ''}`}
          >
            Some Content 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`style.css`

```
.fade {
  transition: opacity var(--TRANSITION_DURATION) linear;
}
.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
.tab-content > :not(.active) {
  display: none;
}
.tab-content > :not(.show) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.tab-content > .active.show {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn var(--TRANSITION_DURATION);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```